# Rails 2.3.x: possible to combine these validations into one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is it possible to keep things DRY and put this into one validation line?

```
  validates_presence_of     :login
  validates_uniqueness_of   :login
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You actually can just remove the `validates_presence_of` line, because `validates_uniqueness_of` defaults to `:allow_blank => false` (and `:allow_nil => false`)

Take a look at the docs [here](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html) .

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 3 (which is not released yet, but please *do* try out the beta) you can!

```
validates :login, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
```